# draw filled circle in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+, picturebox

I have a WinForms application that interacts with a connection. If the connection is fine I want to show a green ("everything is fine") filled circle, if not I want to show a red filled circle.

I found no circle element in the toolbox so I think I have to draw it on my own.

I created a picture box called `picBoxClientState` and started with this code

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public void CheckSignedInState()
    {
        // some other code

        DrawClientStateIcon(client.IsSignedIn);
    }

    private void DrawClientStateIcon(bool isSignedIn)
    {
        Point rectangleLocation = picBoxClientState.Location;
        Size rectangleSize = picBoxClientState.Size;
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(rectangleLocation, rectangleSize);

        Color iconColor = isSignedIn ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
        SolidBrush iconBrush = new SolidBrush(iconColor);

        Graphics graphics = picBoxClientState.CreateGraphics();
        graphics.FillEllipse(iconBrush, rectangle);
    }
}
```

How can I draw on this picturebox whenever I call `CheckSignedInState()` ?

Maybe there is a better way instead of drawing? **(I don't want to toggle two images because there might be more states to draw)**

Comment: you can use [power pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169) to easily create oval shapes

Comment: sorry I just want to draw on this picture box. There is nothing drawn on it although the debugger reaches this code.

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics() to paint.  The iconColor variable must be a field of the class.  Use the pb's Paint event to draw.  When you change iconColor then call the pb's Invalidate() method so it repaints.

Comment: so if I want to paint again I just call `Invalidate()`?

Comment: Yes. Change the data used when drawing and call Invalidate on the control that should Paint.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example using a `Label` control to draw an ellipse.
You can use any control that has a [Paint event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint) to draw shapes.
It could also be a `Panel`, a `PictureBox`, a `Button`...

A `bool` variable (`clientIsSignedIn`) declared at Class scope is used to keep track of the current status, as reported by your `client.IsSignedIn` value.

When the status changes, update `clientIsSignedIn` and [`Invalidate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate) the Control that provides the visual aid.

```
bool clientIsSignedIn = false;

public void CheckSignedInState()
{
    // some other code
    clientIsSignedIn = client.IsSignedIn;
    lblVisualStatus.Invalidate();
}

private void lblVisualStatus_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse((clientIsSignedIn) ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red, ((Control)sender).ClientRectangle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think picture box is necessary. You can try something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new 
    System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
    formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    formGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new Rectangle(200, 200, 30, 30));
    myBrush.Dispose();
    formGraphics.Dispose();
}
```

If you need to draw on picturebox be sure to call picturebox.Invalidate();

Comment: You cannot call this in Load() method of your form, you need to call it from a button.

Comment: but why? where is the difference? I just call a method, no?

Comment: When the form uses Load() it does redraw/Invalidate/Paint a while later, this is where you lose information about your circle. To prevent this you would need to draw your circle in Paint event.

Check this: [Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This works well for me. The using FillEllipse and passing a Brush.  (As opposed to DrawEllipse and passing a pen, which only made a hoollow ellipse). I used the paint event , made use of (PaintEventArgs e), and did e.Graphics.FillEllipse etc.

Answer (score -1):

your code works, it did seem to draw a bit off center though but also the fact that you weren't disposing of the object could potentially cause issues too. Try using the code below as your `DrawClientStateIcon` method

**Edit**: full code example below. I added a button to toggle the state of the client and this works for me.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class Client
        {
            public bool IsSignedIn { get; set; }
        }

        Client client = new Client()
        {
            IsSignedIn = false
        };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void CheckSignedInState()
        {
            // some other code

            DrawClientStateIcon(client.IsSignedIn);
        }

        private void DrawClientStateIcon(bool isSignedIn)
        {
            Point rectangleLocation = picBoxClientState.Location;
            Size rectangleSize = picBoxClientState.Size;
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(rectangleLocation, new Size(rectangleSize.Width / 2, rectangleSize.Height / 2));

            Color iconColor = isSignedIn ? Color.Green : Color.Red;

            using (SolidBrush iconBrush = new SolidBrush(iconColor))
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = picBoxClientState.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    graphics.FillEllipse(iconBrush, rectangle);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.IsSignedIn = !client.IsSignedIn;
            CheckSignedInState();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hm no sorry, nothing gets drawn

Comment: are you sure your code is being hit? I tried your code and it worked for me toggling the client login state with a button, I will edit my code to show the full example

Comment: Yes the debugger hits the line of code. I will try your code snippet in a new project maybe something is missing

Comment: I just tested your code in a new project. I placed a button and a picture box on the form and copy pasted your code. The debugger reaches the line of code but nothing gets drawn.

Comment: Repeating errors from OP (CreateGraphics) is not helpful Hans's advice is all that is needed. I think you should delete this misleading answer!

Answer (score -1):

You need to call it in Form Shown event.

```
        private void FrmGraphics_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawClientStateIcon(true);
        }
        private void DrawClientStateIcon(bool isSignedIn)
        {
            Point rectangleLocation = picBoxClientState.Location;
            Size rectangleSize = picBoxClientState.Size;
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(rectangleLocation, rectangleSize);

            Color iconColor = isSignedIn ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            SolidBrush iconBrush = new SolidBrush(iconColor);

            Graphics graphics = base.CreateGraphics();
            graphics.FillEllipse(iconBrush, rectangle);
        }
```

Comment: Repeating errors from OP (CreateGraphics) is not helpful Hans's advice is all that is needed. I think you should delete this misleading answer!

Comment: why misleading? its a working solution for the mentioned problem. Didn't you see the _Shown method used?

Comment: Have to even looked at the definition of [Shown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) : _Occurs whenever the form is first displayed._ This means it will work only once. Never use `control.CreateGraphics` for graphics meant tp ersist!

Comment: The Graphics object that you retrieve through the CreateGraphics method should not normally be retained after the current Windows message has been processed, because anything painted with that object will be erased with the next WM_PAINT message. Therefore you cannot cache the Graphics object for reuse, except to use non-visual methods like Graphics.MeasureString. Instead, you must call CreateGraphics every time that you want to use the Graphics object, and then call Dispose when you are finished using it.

Comment: Um, indeed. So using it is a mistake. Hans' comment and Jimi's answer got it right.